# Comic about a young girl who gains superpowers from her scientist father

Tags: story-identification, comics, young-adult, powers, graphic-novel

I read this in middle school, so forgive me if the details are somewhat misremembered.

I'm looking for a possibly 2000s to 2010s graphic novel/comic whose main protagonist is a young girl with very long hair (either red or blonde). I believe she was nearly killed and her father used one of his experiments to bring her back to life, but the government could then use her as a soldier since she was technically their property. I remember she recovered from her injury/death in a test tube, and her hair got very long (I'm not sure why). I know her powers include some form of invulnerability and a forcefield. The scene I remember most was her standing on some sort of military ship, her noting that rain doesn't even touch her. Her name was Eve or Eva I think? Though that could be wrong.

The book was relatively short, and it was in a middle-school library, so it must have been appropriate for a child to read. I only ever saw one book, so I don't know if it was a series.

I've tried everything to find this, so any help is much appreciated! Apologies for the scarce details.

I can confirm that it isn't *Invincible Presents: Atom Eve* (2007).

Comment: Probably also not *[Eve](https://arts.columbia.edu/news/eve-new-comic-book-series-professor-victor-lavalle-coming-spring)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some help from the middle school librarians, I've found it! The comic/manga is eV by James Farr, here is a plot description [from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00SKMZNZW):

> Twenty minutes from now, visitors from a far-off world will fall into Earth's orbit and issue a most unexpected request...these "Emissaries" invite a single human being to be selected as a representative for all of Earth in an intergalactic Parliament. Mankind is given five years in which to prepare this volunteed for the rigors of space travel and the intricacies of alien diplomacy. Scientist Dr. Richard Wymond devises the ZETTA serum -- a nano-biological cocktail that will augment its recipient with nearly superhuman abilities. But when Wymond's daughter is mortally injured in a freak accident, he makes a fateful decision, and rather than let her die, he injects Evie with the world's only sample of the ZETTA serum. Now the fate of the world rests on the shoulders of one 17-year-old girl. How will Evie cope with this awesome responsibility? Will she survive the strange political intrigues of Parliament? And more important, are the "Emissaries'" intentions as honorable as they have led us to believe?

From what I can tell, it seems like even if I did have all of the details right, I never would have been able to find it through Google. It is very obscure and also rather poorly received. Much thanks to everyone who tried to help! I appreciate everyone's efforts.